# How do I add trusted certificate to my React Project.?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have 
.cer file
.pfx file
.pem file
.key file

with me.

Dose anybody knows how to add 'valid certificate' in React Project.?

I have changed

```
{
  "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
}
```

by this my project is now running on HTTPS but with localhost's certificate.
How can I add trusted certificate instead of this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a CA certificate to anything, if it's a trusted CA. That's the whole point of them.

Comment: let's say I have a valid certificate of 'example.com' and mine react project is also going to be deployed on https://example.com:3000. 

For this I have to import example.com's certificate in React Project.

Comment: React is for frontend code (the code that goes into a browser and is executed there). It doesn't care about serverside much. *react-scripts* provide you with dev server that shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: if you want to test locally on a domain like `example.com`, you have to make a record in i.e. `hosts` file to point request to `example.com` to 127.0.0.1 and then create CA for tests, add it to trusted hosts and then one way to go is set up nginx as a reverse proxy to take care of https and then forward requests to dev server.

Comment: can you elaborate more about what you want to do with the certificate? the are many things you can use it for in React, like JWT token generation, or maybe you mean serving React through HTTPS (which has nothing to do with react actually), more information can help addressing your issue.

Comment: I want to serve React through HTTPS. With valid certificate of Go Daddy which I am having with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

I put my valid certificate files (not self-certified) into `....node_modules\webpack-dev-server\ssl-folder`.

Before that I removed all files from that folder to somewhere, just in case if they are needed later.

I set an environment variable with

```
SET HTTPS=true
```

I run command `npm start`, and got errors that it can't find files: `ssl\server.crt`, `ssl\server.key` and `ssl\ca.crt` (actually, it complained about those one by one).

Then I renamed my valid certificate files to have those names. For example I renamed `Intermediate.crt` file to `ca.crt`.

All files begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` or `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` if there was something before that, I removed it.

Then I restarted with `npm start` and opened Chrome with that url for which the certificate is made for. Chrome showed the lock icon before url and did not complain anymore about 'not secure...'.

EDIT:

Above mentioned installation does not have a `server.pem` file at it still works.
In another installation I did the same as above but it did not work. Then I combined `server.key` and `server.crt` files (which were renamed from my valid certificate files) into one file `server.pem`. That `server.pem` file originally was created automatically but it did not help anything before I replaced it. After that the https-connection was accepted without any complains from the Chrome.